# Is there a substitute for xdoclet that supports generics?

Tags: java, generics, ejb, xdoclet

I have an old EJB (2.1) project that uses xdoclet (1.2.3) to generate the EJB interfaces. Unfortunately xdoclet makes it impossible to use generics in the method signatures.

Is there a substitute or other way to to allow generics in the parameters?

Here is the minimum type of generics use I'm looking for:

```
 public Object ejbMethod(Collection<String> param) { return null;}
```

Of course the more the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check [XDT-1581](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/xdoclet/browse/XDT-1581), it has an (unreleased) patch for support of generics in the xdoclet EJB module. I didn't test it though.

PS: AFAIK, [XDoclet 2](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/XDOCLET/Home) (which has an [Ejb plugin](http://xdoclet.codehaus.org/Ejb+plugin)) has support for generics.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing xjavadoc-1.x.jar with the latest in the library. ( Moving from xjavadoc-1.1.jar  to xjavadoc-1.5.jar worked for me)